# What does this error mean?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

> /tmp/ccjiJKv2.o: In function `func':
>
>   b.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to`sqrt'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the code and I am using gcc compiler..

```
/*Write a function that receive 5 integers and returns the sum,average and standard deviation of these numbers*/

/*Author:Udit Gupta     Date:10/08/2011*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void func (int *,float *,float *);

int main () {

        float avg,std_dev;

        int sum;

        func (&sum,&avg,&std_dev);      /*Passing address of variables where output will be stored.....*/

        printf ("The sum of numbers is %d\n",sum);
        printf ("The average of numbers is %f\n",avg);
        printf ("The standard deviation of numbers is %f\n",std_dev);

}


void func (int *sum_, float *avg_ , float * std_dev_) {

        int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;

        printf("Please enter the number:");
                scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&n1,&n2,&n3,&n4,&n5);


        /*Formula for sum,average and standard deviation*/

        *sum_ = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5;                 /*Writing output at the address specified by arguments of function*/
        *avg_ = *sum_ / 5 ;
        *std_dev_ = sqrt ( pow((n1-*avg_),2)+pow((n2-*avg_),2)+pow ((n3-*avg_),2)+pow ((n4-*avg_),2)+pow ((n5-*avg_),2)/4) ;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <math.h> - is this what you need?
```

Also, `Link with -lm`

Comment: Looking at the edit, I *think* that the code already had `#include <math.h>`; probably it wasn't marked as code, and the `<` and `>` were taken as HTML symbols.  The lack of `-lm` is what caused the problem.

Comment: sorry I added the library in code but forgot here.... but editing library creates no change in error

Comment: So, adding `lm` is not solving the problem?

Comment: gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) - works pretty well on my linux box.

Comment: You may probably want to use `-Wall` option for `gcc` to catch all warnings. - Just to be sure.

Comment: gcc: unrecognized option '-1m'  and prev. error also remains there

Comment: You do not need to `uninstall` gcc. Just use correct options and it must work.

Comment: @UditGupta let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2422/discussion-between-hari-and-udit-gupta)

Comment: @hari thanks buddy.......Its worked but I have a question Do I need to link each new function in this manner whenever used a new library

Comment: @Udit Gupta: So, each lib has functions defined in them, in this case `sqrt` is in lib math. At the same time, lib math has many more functions. To cut it short, yes, you need to link against the library of functions you want to use.

Comment: I got same errors many a times ... but do we need to do same for printf.I got an error in a different program i.e.  Undefined Reference To 'printf'

Comment: AFAIK, `printf` is a part of `libc` which is a basic/common library so you do not need to link it explicitly. Please paste the code in a another que for that problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are not linking the library which contains the *implementation* of sqrt.

That library is known as "libm" (the math library), and can be linked to as follows:

```
gcc -o myprog infile.c -lm
```

Comment: gcc: unrecognized option '-1m'
     /tmp/ccpWiDRt.o: In function `func':
     b.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `sqrt'
     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Lower case "L", not 1. Please adjust your font.

Answer (score 2):

you have to link the math library. `-lm`

Comment: here is the right code I had added the library jst forgot to paste here before..nw Its the actual code getting error